# Is it possible to authenticate to Google Cloud Storage in C++ with a credentials struct?

Tags: c++, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using the Google Cloud client library for C++ to access Google Cloud Storage and perform operations. I have a struct containing credentials to initialise a GCS Client:

```
struct credentials {
  std::string bucket;
  std::string access_key;
  std::string secret_key;
};
```

I need to be able to authenticate using defined credentials, rather than using gcloud / setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable / JSON files.

I have tried *hardcoding* credentials and passing into the GCS Client constructor, i.e:

```
auto client = gcs::Client(google::cloud::Options{}.set<google::cloud::UnifiedCredentialsOption>(credentials));
```

Any ideas on how I can authenticate this way?

Comment: Have you tried using a service account JSON credentials file import then initialise the client with the credentials? That's the recommended way of gaining auth.

Comment: I could be wrong, but there is nothing in the Google Cloud Storage C++ SDK that supports HMAC authorization. The SDK is built using OAuth and service accounts. I have reviewed the SDK source, class headers, and this link: https://cloud.google.com/cpp/docs/reference/common/latest/group__guac.html

Comment: What John said.  As to "why no HMAC authentication?" Because the C++ SDK uses the JSON API, and the JSON API only supports OAuth2 authentication. And "why not use the XML API, which does support HMAC?" Because there are features available in the JSON API which are not available in the XML API.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. In regards to OAuth2 authentication - If I were to use an external OAuth2 library to generate an access token, would it be possible to use ```google::cloud::MakeAccessTokenCredentials``` to initialise a client?

Comment: One problem per post. Your original question has been answered. Create a new question with details.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Cloud Storage C++ SDK does not support HMAC authorization.

When Google first released Cloud Storage, it implemented the AWS S3 HMAC authorization mechanism and the XML API.

Google also released the native JSON API which uses the OAuth mechanism.

The Google Cloud Storage C++ SDK is based on the JSON API which does not support the XML API or the HMAC authorization mechanism.

If your only option is HMAC authorization, you could bypass the SDK and drop down to the [XML API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/overview) and implement your features.